# Regexp: Anything but a number or nothing at all

Tags: regex

I suppose it's a pretty basic issue but I just can't figure it out:

Should match:

```
A12
A12.1
A12.123
```

Should not match:

```
A1
A123
A13
```

My guess was A12[^0-9] but this way "A12" doesn't match. `A12[^0-9]|A12` would be a workaround but I was looking for something more elegant.

Comment: `A12` does not match with your first try because `[^0-9]` consumes a character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A12(?!\d)
```

fulfills your requirements exactly as stated: Match `A12` unless it's followed by a number.

Answer (score 2):

In your regex you never talk about the `.` that you mention in the example. Anyway, you can use `?` like below:

```
A12(\.\d+)?
```

Answer (score 1):

How does that sound ?

```
A12(\.\d+)?$
```

This would match A12 and A12.some_digits

Answer (score 0):

```
A12[^0-9]?
```

The ? makes the part in the brackets optional.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a solution...
*^A12(.\d{0,})?*